# DataframeIndex duplicated values found when they don't exist

Tags: python, pandas, pycaret

I have the following dataset where the index is DatetimeIndex and the column "value" is made of floats. The index: creationDate contains only information of the day 2020-06-13.

`df`

[image]

`df[df.index.duplicated()]`

[image]

The day is the same but not the hour or the minute, so I'm confused of what is happening here, is it only filtering by day? but why those exact values from the dataset? Is there any way to filter by hour? Or creating a DatetimeIndex only by hour/minute/second ? Thanks!

I know I can convert it to a string and then use it only the hour/minute/second information, but will this remove the possibility to create the DatetimeIndex aswell?

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.Index.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) returns a boolean array, in which for each set of duplicated values, the **first** occurrence is set to `False` and all others to `True`. In short, it finds the duplicated index.

Your case is that your two `2020-06-13` index are duplicated in original index thus you select these two rows with `df[df.index.duplicated()]`.

It means in your original index it might like

```py
2020-06-13 20:38:53
2020-06-13 20:38:53
2020-06-13 21:39:01
2020-06-13 21:39:01
```

so `df.index.duplicated()` will return `[False, True, False, True]`. Then you use the boolean indexing to choose the duplicated index.

Comment: It is the same date (2020-06-13) but different hours,

Comment: @a.civit Those different hours duplicated in original index, see my edited answer.